# How to configure Emacs (v 23) with nxhtml to follow Kohana coding standards?

Tags: php, emacs, nxhtml

I am trying to configure Emacs v23 to follow Kohana coding standards for PHP. I am using Emacs with nxhtml plugin.

I can see the indent-tabs-mode is set to t in the buffer, but when I press tab to indent the code, I see two spaces are inserted not the TAB character.

What could be wrong?

Here the content of my .emacs:

```
(server-start)
;;php mode
(add-hook 'nxhtml-mumamo-mode-hook
        (lambda ()
        (setq indent-tabs-mode t)
        ))

(load "/home/sabya/install/emacs-stuff/nxhtml/autostart.el")
```

Comment: I ran into the same problem; I posted a question (with some more details) on the nXhtml site—https://answers.launchpad.net/nxhtml/+question/181005. If I get an answer, of course I'll post it here...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was a [bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/nxhtml/+bug/900520) in mumamo, now [fixed](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~nxhtml/nxhtml/main/revision/829?start_revid=829).

Answer (score 0):

In your .emacs that should do the job:

```
(setq c-default-style "bsd"
      c-basic-offset 4)
```